# How do I get Consul to work so I can get Docker Overlay to work?

Tags: centos, networking, tcp, docker

I am running CentOS 7 with Docker. I am trying to install Consul on the Docker server. Consul is unzipped. The binary file works for showing the version. I ran this:

```
echo $CONSUL_RPC_ADDR
```

This returns a blank line. I then ran this:

```
consul join x.x.x.x #where x.x.x.x is the IP address of the server
```

I get this:

> Error connecting to Consul agent: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8400: getsockopt:
>   connection refused

I then ran this:

```
consul info
```

I saw this as the result:

> Error connecting to Consul agent: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8400: getsockopt:
>   connection refused

I checked, port 8400 is not blocked. What should I do to get Consul to work? I want to get Docker overlay to work.